# Matlab Fourier transform of dsp.Audiorecorder in real-time

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, audio-recording

I'm using `dsp.Audiorecord` to get real-time microphone input. The sound input is a series of sinusoids with different frequencies ranging from 500 to 2000Hz. Each one sounds for a second.

I'd like to know in real-time, what's the frequency of the current sin and also make the difference between two sins with same frequency going one after the other. This is why I use `dsp.Audiorecord`.

This is what my code looks like now:

```
Microphone = dsp.AudioRecorder;
tic;
while(toc<30)
    audio = step(Microphone);
    [x, indexMax] = max(abs(fft(audio(:,1)-mean(audio(:,1)))));
    indexMax
end
```

All the `indexMax` shows are numbers ranging from around 25 to 40. There's clearly an operation left out in order to retrieve the original frequency in [500;2000].

I've tried also to apply `dsp.FFT()` directly to audio but it tells me:

```
Error using dsp.FFT/pvParse
Invalid property/value pair arguments.
```

If there's any other way to perform real-time FFT on the `dsp.Audiorecorder` I'd really like to know. Or just if you see a way to to complete what I've done here it would be great also.

Comment: I've never heard of this kind of data representation, is it like the name says "in order" frequency representation? Because if it is I think I could make use of that :)

Comment: hotpaw2 has your answer. To dsp.FFT you first create the object using fftObj = dsp.FFT; and then use it by calling the step method as in y = step(fftObj, u);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approximately estimate what frequency goes with what index, you need to know the sample rate (Fs) of the data sent to the FFT, and the length (N) of the FFT:

```
f ~= index * Fs / N
```

That's the operation you've left out.